# Opa exectuable error: Can't get system language

Tags: opa

I'm just learning the Opa language and going through their Manual. In the third section of the Manual, it shows you how to build the app "Hello, chat".

I have copied and pasted the .css and .opa files and have buit the .exe file. When I run it, I get the following error:

[warn]: I18n ServerI18n.get_system_lang can't get system language

What gives?
Thanks

Comment: What architecture are you on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a warning because the server tries to guess you server language (for use with the [i18n module](http://doc.opalang.org/module/stdlib.core.i18n/I18n).

You can set LANG or LANGUAGE env variable to avoid it.